# returning multiple rows from postgre PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I get no results returned with this PHP postgreSQL PDO statement. I expected to see several rows. What have I done wrong? How can I retrieve them and put them into an object or array?

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM address');
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($row = $sth->fetch()) {  
    echo $row['StreetAddress1'] . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the result set a stack, and each fetch() call pops off a result row. You've called fetch once OUTSIDE of the while loop, and then apparently thrown away $result. That means one row of result data is gone. As for putting them into an object/array, that's up to you. could be as simple as:

```
$addresses[] = $row['StreetAddress1']
```

inside the loop.

---

either

```
while($row = $sth->fetch()) {
   ...
}

-- or --

$rows = $sth->fetchAll();
foreach($rows as $row) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand how the fetch() should be put inside the while loop(?)

Comment: I see. However, `foreach($result as $key=>$val) {  
    echo $val . "\n";
}` simply displays `Array Array`. While `foreach($result as $key=>$val) {  
    echo $val['StreetAddress1'] . "\n";
}` displays nothing. :/ I still can't see the data..

Answer (score 0):

`$result = $sth->fetchAll();`

`$result` will be an array with all your results.

Then use a `foreach` to loop through.

[foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: `foreach($result as $key=>$val) { echo $val;}` simply gives me `Array Array`, whereas `foreach($result as $key=>$val) {  
    foreach($val as $k=>$v){
  echo $v . "<br>";
 }
}` prints out the first row of data twice (the number of rows in the table). How can I correct this? Thank you.